# Word for "Accessible to all": omni

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that means accessible to all? Possibly starting with "omni"?

Specifically, to describe information: information that could be accessed by anyone is [omni...]

"Public" would be a reasonable description, but perhaps there are similar words. The problem is that "public" information is not necessarily accessible. Scientific journals are public, but are not necessarily free to access. Books are public, but not everyone can access a library, etc.

I suppose it doesn't have to be a specific word. I wanted a convenient term for describing the kind of information that does not currently exist: information that in an ideal world everyone could get to

(Edited in response to the many valid comments)

Comment: *Omni-* is a generative suffix, meaning it can be added to all kinds of roots. For example, you can use *omni-accessible* or *omniaccessible*.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an information that would be "public" but not "accessible"? In my mind they go together.

Comment: In the case of academic journals, there's _open access_. In general, _open_ (and various related terms starting with _open_) could be a candidate, but _open_ often implies something about distribution and redistribution rights too.

Comment: Do you have an example of some information that fits the description of the word you're searching for?

Comment: More information about the specific context would be useful.  Until I read the comments above, I thought the concern was with DDA/ADA issues.

Comment: "general audience" information.

Comment: Why does it need to be a single word?  Why not *broadly available* or *unlimited access*?

Comment: Or "freely available"?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `ubiquitous`:
adjective

> existing or being everywhere, especially at the same time; omnipresent

:
*ubiquitous information*